# Unable to parse composition when using lotti animation designed in Haiku

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, lottie, haiku

I have created the following lotti animation using `Haiku`

```
{"ip":0,"fr":60,"v":"5.1.20","assets":[],"layers":[{"ty":4,"nm":"path006","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":8,"hix":2,"ks":{"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100],"i":{"x":[0.515],"y":[0.955]},"o":{"x":[0.455],"y":[0.03]}},{"t":24}]},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[6.505775451660156,6.521575927734375,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":320.292},"y":{"a":0,"k":236.563}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"path006 shape group","it":[{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[182.1413,189.58125],[184.18636,185.01671000000002],[185.96810000000002,180.34254],[176.78334,176.53809],[175.02166,181.22057],[172.95654,185.7768]],"i":[[0,0],[-0.642169999999993,1.5503400000000056],[-0.5469100000000253,1.5649899999999946],[0,0],[0.6431100000000072,-1.5526099999999872],[0.7295000000000016,-1.4875000000000114]],"o":[[0.7197999999999922,-1.4931799999999953],[0.6422399999999868,-1.5504999999999995],[0,0],[-0.5360200000000077,1.567910000000012],[-0.6430100000000039,1.5523699999999963],[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[182.1413,189.58125]],"i":[[0,0]],"o":[[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"w":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"lc":3,"lj":1,"ml":1},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.16470588235294117,0.16470588235294117,1]}},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-172.957,-176.538]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28},{"ty":4,"nm":"path007","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":7,"hix":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100],"i":{"x":[0.515],"y":[0.955]},"o":{"x":[0.455],"y":[0.03]}},{"t":28}]},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[7.05035400390625,7.05035400390625,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":302.413},"y":{"a":0,"k":263.321}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"path007 shape group","it":[{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[161.56254,216.86804],[165.1987,213.43357],[168.63354,209.79704],[161.60383000000002,202.76733000000002],[158.18434000000002,206.41921000000002],[154.53283000000002,209.83833]],"i":[[0,0],[-1.1865799999999922,1.1865799999999922],[-1.1041700000000105,1.2365700000000004],[0,0],[1.1883200000000045,-1.1883100000000013],[1.2432100000000048,-1.0951000000000022]],"o":[[1.2364200000000096,-1.104060000000004],[1.1867000000000019,-1.1867000000000019],[0,0],[-1.0952299999999866,1.2434399999999926],[-1.188130000000001,1.1881400000000042],[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[161.56254,216.86804]],"i":[[0,0]],"o":[[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"w":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"lc":3,"lj":1,"ml":1},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.16470588235294117,0.16470588235294117,1]}},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-154.533,-202.767]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28},{"ty":4,"nm":"path005","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":6,"hix":3,"ks":{"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100],"i":{"x":[0.515],"y":[0.955]},"o":{"x":[0.455],"y":[0.03]}},{"t":20}]},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[5.0420684814453125,4.9999542236328125,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":326.642},"y":{"a":0,"k":205}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"path005 shape group","it":[{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[190.71139,156.49639],[190.85401,151.49669],[190.71139,146.49648],[180.76988,146.49648],[180.93421,151.49669],[180.76988,156.49639]],"i":[[0,0],[0,1.6780799999999942],[0.09361999999998716,1.6551500000000203],[0,0],[0,-1.6805300000000045],[0.10473000000001775,-1.6534399999999891]],"o":[[0.09360000000000923,-1.6549799999999948],[0,-1.6782499999999914],[0,0],[0.10480000000001155,1.6536900000000117],[0,1.6802800000000104],[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[190.71139,156.49639]],"i":[[0,0]],"o":[[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"w":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"lc":3,"lj":1,"ml":1},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.16470588235294117,0.16470588235294117,1]}},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-180.77,-146.496]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28},{"ty":4,"nm":"path004","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":5,"hix":4,"ks":{"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100],"i":{"x":[0.515],"y":[0.955]},"o":{"x":[0.455],"y":[0.03]}},{"t":16}]},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[6.5057830810546875,6.521583557128906,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":320.292},"y":{"a":0,"k":173.437}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"path004 shape group","it":[{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[185.9681,122.65033],[184.18656,117.97663],[182.14129,113.41161],[172.95653,117.21606],[175.02184999999997,121.77277],[176.78333999999998,126.45478]],"i":[[0,0],[0.642169999999993,1.5503300000000024],[0.719869999999986,1.4933400000000034],[0,0],[-0.6430999999999756,-1.5525999999999982],[-0.5359500000000139,-1.56768000000001]],"o":[[-0.5468700000000126,-1.5648099999999943],[-0.6422300000000121,-1.5504999999999995],[0,0],[0.7296699999999987,1.4877000000000038],[0.6430100000000039,1.552359999999993],[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[185.9681,122.65033]],"i":[[0,0]],"o":[[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"w":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"lc":3,"lj":1,"ml":1},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.16470588235294117,0.16470588235294117,1]}},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-172.957,-113.412]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28},{"ty":4,"nm":"path003","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":4,"hix":5,"ks":{"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100],"i":{"x":[0.515],"y":[0.955]},"o":{"x":[0.455],"y":[0.03]}},{"t":12}]},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[7.050361633300781,7.050357818603516,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":302.413},"y":{"a":0,"k":146.679}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"path003 shape group","it":[{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[168.63354,93.195832],[165.19907,89.559658],[161.56253,86.12482299999999],[154.53281,93.15453099999999],[158.18470000000002,96.57401399999999],[161.60383000000002,100.22554]],"i":[[0,0],[1.1865700000000174,1.1865739999999931],[1.236549999999994,1.1041810000000112],[0,0],[-1.1882999999999981,-1.1883069999999947],[-1.0950799999999958,-1.2432470000000109]],"o":[[-1.1040700000000072,-1.2364180000000005],[-1.1867000000000019,-1.1867029999999943],[0,0],[1.2434499999999957,1.0952259999999967],[1.188130000000001,1.1881290000000035],[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[168.63354,93.195832]],"i":[[0,0]],"o":[[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"w":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"lc":3,"lj":1,"ml":1},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.16470588235294117,0.16470588235294117,1]}},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-154.533,-86.125]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28},{"ty":4,"nm":"path002","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":3,"hix":6,"ks":{"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100],"i":{"x":[0.515],"y":[0.955]},"o":{"x":[0.455],"y":[0.03]}},{"t":8}]},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[6.5215911865234375,6.505779266357422,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":275.655},"y":{"a":0,"k":128.8}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"path002 shape group","it":[{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[141.34675,72.61707],[136.78221,70.571998],[132.10802999999999,68.790268],[128.30356999999998,77.975028],[132.98604999999998,79.73670299999999],[137.54229999999998,81.80182799999999]],"i":[[0,0],[1.5503300000000024,0.6421700000000072],[1.5649700000000166,0.5469250000000017],[0,0],[-1.5525900000000092,-0.6431109999999904],[-1.4875000000000114,-0.7295409999999976]],"o":[[-1.4931899999999985,-0.7197900000000033],[-1.5504999999999995,-0.642240000000001],[0,0],[1.5679199999999867,0.5360100000000045],[1.5523699999999963,0.6430090000000064],[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[141.34675,72.61707]],"i":[[0,0]],"o":[[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"w":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"lc":3,"lj":1,"ml":1},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.16470588235294117,0.16470588235294117,1]}},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-128.304,-68.79]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28},{"ty":4,"nm":"pathTheCircle","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":2,"hix":8,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[95.09270477294922,95.09270477294922,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":244},"y":{"a":0,"k":205}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"pathTheCircle shape group","it":[{"ty":"el","p":{"a":0,"k":[103,151]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[190.18541,190.18541]}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,1,0,1]},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":4,"w":{"a":0,"k":9.81459045},"d":[{"n":"d","v":{"a":0,"k":null},"nm":"0"},{"n":"g","v":{"a":0,"k":null},"nm":"1"},{"n":"o","v":{"a":0,"k":0},"nm":"2"}]},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"r":1},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-8.078,-56.404]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28},{"ty":4,"nm":"path001","ip":0,"st":0,"ind":1,"hix":7,"ks":{"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100],"i":{"x":[0.515],"y":[0.955]},"o":{"x":[0.455],"y":[0.03]}},{"t":4}]},"or":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0]},"a":{"a":0,"k":[4.999961853027344,5.042074203491211,0]},"p":{"s":true,"x":{"a":0,"k":244.092},"y":{"a":0,"k":122.45}},"rx":{"a":0,"k":0},"ry":{"a":0,"k":0},"rz":{"a":0,"k":0},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100]}},"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","nm":"path001 shape group","it":[{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[108.26189,64.046974],[103.26218999999999,63.904348000000006],[98.26197799999998,64.04697300000001],[98.26196799999998,73.98849000000001],[103.26217999999999,73.82415700000001],[108.26189,73.98848500000001]],"i":[[0,0],[1.6780700000000053,0],[1.6551430000000096,-0.09359500000000054],[0,0],[-1.6805200000000013,-0.0000040000000041118255],[-1.6534500000000065,-0.10476799999999287]],"o":[[-1.6549799999999948,-0.09358000000000288],[-1.6782500000000056,-0.0000020000000020559128],[0,0],[1.6536940000000016,-0.10481000000000051],[1.680269999999993,-0.0000019999999949504854],[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"sh","ks":{"a":0,"k":{"c":true,"v":[[108.26189,64.046974]],"i":[[0,0]],"o":[[0,0]]}}},{"ty":"st","o":{"a":0,"k":0},"w":{"a":0,"k":0},"c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,0]},"lc":3,"lj":1,"ml":1},{"ty":"fl","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"r":1,"c":{"a":0,"k":[1,0.16470588235294117,0.16470588235294117,1]}},{"ty":"tr","o":{"a":0,"k":100},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0]},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100]},"p":{"a":0,"k":[-98.262,-63.904]},"r":{"a":0,"k":0}}]}],"op":28}],"op":28,"w":550,"h":400}
```

I have saved the above file as `raw/dashboardsupercharger.json`

I am using the above animation like so in my splash screen activity like so :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#50baff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/dashboardsupercharger"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i run my application i get the folllowing error :-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to parse composition
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView$1.onResult(LottieAnimationView.java:74)
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The exception should have a cause as well. Can you include it to help us understand the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/1140

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at above link I posted?